# Javascript Modal Animation not Working When Close

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a Simple javascript modal that I've collected from W3 Schools. It's easy and light. But the fact is, when I click on modal button, it appears with slide up animation and also an overlay animation. But when click on close button or click outside, modal get disappear or close without any animation. I want to add an animation on modal closing time. That's mean, there will be an animation on Both, modal appear and disappearing time. With overlay, like appear time. How can Indo it....?

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  /* Fade in the background */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    bottom: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    bottom: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Bottom Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Updated code:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.classList.add('animate-out');

  modal.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    modal.classList.remove('animate-out');
  }, {
    once: true
  });
}

span.onclick = closeModal;
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.closest('#myModal') === null) {
    closeModal();
  }
};
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  /* Fade in the background */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    bottom: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    bottom: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.modal.animate-out {
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}

.modal.animate-out .modal-content {
  animation-name: slideOut;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 300px, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Bottom Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your "in" animation works is by first changing the `display` property to `block` which renders the element visible. That also triggers the `animation` that is set on the modal.

The "out" animation has to work in the reverse order. First you have to animate the modal out. Whenever the animation is finished change the `display` property to `none`.

First define the animation. It should be the reverse keyframes of `fadeIn` and `slideIn`.

```
@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  } 
  
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 300px, 0);
  } 
  
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Also add a class that uses this animation. That way we can add the animation the `.modal` to overwrite the style.

```
.modal.animate-out {
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}

.modal.animate-out .modal-content {
  animation-name: slideOut;
}
```

To trigger the animation you'll only need to add the `animate-out` class we've just created to the modal once you click the close button. Then immediately add an event listener that listens for the `animationend` event. This event will trigger whenever the animation has finished, which in this case is our fade out animation.

After it finishes set `display` to `none` and remove the `animate-out` class from the modal to reset the animation so that a fade in can happen next time we show the modal. The `{ once: true }` part ensures that this event is only listened to **once**. This is important since there are multiple animations but we only want the `display: none` and removal of the `animate-out` class to happen on the fade out animation.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.classList.add('animate-out');

  modal.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    modal.classList.remove('animate-out');
  }, { once: true });
}

span.onclick = closeModal;

document.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('#myModal')) {
    closeModal();
  }
};
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

.modal.animate-out {
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}

.modal-content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

.modal.animate-out .modal-content {
  animation-name: slideOut;
}

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 300px, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 300px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Bottom Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working... Please write a complete code brother..

Comment: It's not working is not very descriptive. If you want to help out, please create the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by editing your question and creating a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) (look for the <> icon in the question editor). That way we can run your code on this page and make adjustments to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250478/discussion-between-asma-binta-younus-and-emiel-zuurbier).

Comment: Brother, I've updated my code with your new code. Please just check it.

Comment: Thank you for the snippet. That helps a lot with figuring out what went wrong. I've modified the answer with a working snippet. For future reference: W3Schools doesn't always use best practices or examples are sometimes outdated. Be sure to look for the most recent, tested and peer-proofed examples to solve your code.